# How to repair crack between wall and roof?

Tags: roof

How should I repair this crack? It is cedar shake roof. Looks like it separated from the wall about 1/4 inch.

[image]

Comment: Was the brick built on *top* of the shakes?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain. The brick part was a later addition to the house. But I don't know if the roof, which is a garage door eyebrow was also added at that time or was there previously.

Comment: More information is needed. Is that real brick or "thin brick"? Is there flashing in place? How far under the brick do the shakes go? Normally siding and roofing aren't mated so closely like that--there's a gap for drainage.

Answer (score 1):

This appears as if the brick was installed after the roof was in place.
The correct way is to caulk the joint with a polyurethane sealant (to allow for movement) and install a step flashing that overlaps the shingles following the mortar joint to protect the intersection between the brick and the shingles.